# MPI Scatter/Gather scope of variables

Tags: c, malloc, mpi, scatter

I'm dealing with MPI version of BML automaton but MPI_Scatter() won't work as I expected. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789067/mpi-scatter-why-do-i-have-to-allocate-memory-in-all-the-processes) that for collective communication functions every process needs its copy of the array, just the allocated space without initialization. In my code there is a subgrid `local_grid` that every process manipulates, and a starting big `grid` that only root manipulate. I mean to use a Scatter-Gather communication with MPI Datatype. I allocate space for grid and sub-grid for every one, and then initialize the grid only for the root. Where am I wrong?

```
        unsigned char*** local_grid;
        unsigned char** grid;

        MPI_Status stat;
        MPI_Datatype rowtype;

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
        local_n = N / nproc;

        MPI_Type_contiguous(N + 2,    /* count */
                MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR,    /* oldtype */
                &rowtype              /* newtype */
                );
        MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

        /* Allocate space for 3D local grids*/
        local_grid = (unsigned char***)malloc(2 * sizeof(unsigned char**));
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            local_grid[i] = (unsigned char**)malloc((local_n + 2) * sizeof(unsigned char*));
            for(j = 0; j < local_n + 2; j++) {
                local_grid[i][j] = (unsigned char*)malloc((N + 2) * sizeof(unsigned char));
            }
        }
        /* Initialize local grids*/
        for(i = 0; i < local_n + 2; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < N + 2; j++) {
                local_grid[0][i][j] = 0;
                local_grid[1][i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        /* Allocate 2D starting grid */
        grid = (unsigned char**)malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned char*));
        for(i = 0; i < N + 2; i++) {
            grid[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc((N + 2) * sizeof(unsigned char));
        }
        /* Root */
        if(rank == 0) {
            /* initialize 2D starting grid */
            for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < N + 2; j++) {
                    grid[i][j] = (((float)rand())/RAND_MAX) > rho ? 0 : rand()%2 + 1;
                    grid[i][0] = grid[i][N+1] = 0;
                    printf("%2d ", grid[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        /* All */
        MPI_Scatter(grid[0], local_n, rowtype, local_grid[cur][1], local_n, rowtype, source, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        ...
```

Program terminates correctly, but only one single rowtype row is passed from Scatter() to root process, nothing to any other process despite of their number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue comes from the way you declare/allocate your 2D arrays.

you declared your 2D arrays as arrays of pointers to arrays (e.g. matrix rows), but MPI expects a contiguous layout.

for example, you can replace

```
grid = (unsigned char**)malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned char*));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    grid[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc((N + 2) * sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

with

```
    grid = (unsigned char**)malloc(N * sizeof(unsigned char*));
    grid[0] = (unsigned char*)malloc(N*(N+2)*sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        grid[i] = grid[i-1] + N + 2;
    }
```

and then use `grid[0]` as the buffer argument for `MPI_Scatter()` or `MPI_Gather()`
the same thing must be applied to `local_grid[0]` and `local_grid[1]`

when you need to free the grid, you can simply

```
free(grid[0]);
free(grid);
```

note i do not think your program can work correctly if `N` is not a multiple of `nproc`

Comment: What happens inside loop?. So if you want to pass a sub-grid, 2D or 3D, in MPI_Gather/Scatter function without knowing parameters, is this the typical way you would do? I will fix N/nproc details later, i know that.

Comment: i am sorry i am having some hard time understanding your comment. `grid` is an array of pointers. since you are using this in MPI, you need to ensure `grid[1][0]` is right next to `grid[0][N+1]`. the method i described does exactly that : allocate the full array all at once, and then build the array of pointers so they all point to the full array. btw, i just noted an error in your allocation and i repeated it: it should be `for(i=0; i<N; i++)`

Comment: Ok, so for the 3D array `grid[1][0][0]` should be next to `grid[0][N+1][N+1]` ? I can't figure out how to write it, I imagine with a nested loop(?).

Comment: this is correct. note you do not need to worry about these things if you use Fortran instead of C ... that being said, Fortran arrays are stored by columns (e.g. `a[1][0]` follows `a[0][0]`) when C arrays are stored by rows (e.g. `a[0][1]` follows `a[0][0]`)

Comment: _"in C, a 2D array is really an array of pointers"_ - not true. Intrinsic arrays of any dimension (e.g. `int a[M][N][P]`) in C are contiguous. Discontinuous are multidimensional arrays when specifically implemented as arrays of pointers. In modern C dialects the cleanest option (in my own opinion) is to use a pointer to an array of a given dimension, e.g. `int (*grid)[M][N][P] = malloc(...)`.

Comment: `int a[M][N][P]` is contiguous in C only if `M,N,P` are known at compile time, right ?

Comment: Not necessary. C99 allows arrays of varying sizes and declaring `a` that way works also when the values of `M`, `N`, and `P` are only known at run time. The only problem is that C11 made it an optional feature.

Comment: @HristoIliev thanks, i edited the answer based on your feedback

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok, I'm trying to write the nested loop to allocate correctly the 3D arrays(the 2D seems to work), that if I understand in c99(the one I use) is a pointer to an array of arrays of array of unsigned char. About Fortran... it's not an option. What about if I use two 2D arrays, let's say 'current' and 'next', instead a 3D?

Comment: @HristoIliev Infact if I declare `a[M][N][P]` and move declaration after knowing parameters, it works. But there are some changes to do in other functions because the result it's not correct for some reason I still don't know. But I'm afraid It's not a good practice having declaration after some code, isn't it?

Comment: are you passing only 2D arrays to MPI ? if yes, then it will be easier to use 2 2D arrays instead of one 3D array `a[2][M][N]` (fwiw, in this case, `a[1][0][0]` does not need to be next to `a[0][M-1][N-1]`)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, I'm using only Scatter/Gather() and Send/Recv() with thees 2D arrays. S/G  for communication with root process and S/R when sub-grids exchange their edge rows every step, that become the gosth rows of their neighbourhoods(in a cyclic domain).

Comment: @HristoIliev When you say _"Discontinuous are multidimensional arrays when specifically implemented as arrays of pointers"_ you refer for example to my `unsigned char*** local_grid` declaration?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks, that worked for me. Finally I made two 2D arrays initialized as you suggested and now program runs correctly. I think there's no reason to public my final code because it's exactly the one in your answer.